# Intercept only the outermost decorator

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm working on a project that uses Castle Windsor, with a mix of decorators and dynamic interception being used to add functionality to the root implementations.

For example, suppose I'm working on a portion of the data access layer that needs to do some caching as well as general-purpose error logging, as implemented with the following:

```
interface IRepository 
{ 
    /* . . . */ 
}

// base implementation
class SqlRepository : IRepository
{ 
    /* . . . */ 
}

// decorator to implement caching
class CachingRepository : IRepository
{ 
    private readonly IRepository _base;

    /* . . . */ 
}

// interceptor to implement generic logging
class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{ 
    /* . . . */ 
}
```

So far so good, except that I'm unsure of how best to implement the pointcut.  I want to ensure that the interceptor is not applied to every object in the chain of decorators.  Instead it should only be applied to the outermost decorator.  In this case, it should be getting applied to `CachingRepository` and not `SqlRepository`.  I've got a lot of classes in the actual solution, so if possible I'd like to use an interceptor selector to do it in order to avoid a lot of repetitive code for manually applying interceptors.

And that's where I get stuck.  Obviously I don't want to hard-code it into the `IModelInterceptorsSelector`, since the specific object which needs to have the interceptor supplied might be different whenever the selection of decorators or the order in which they're applied changes.  At that point I'm sure it would be a lot easier to stick with manual registration. And I can't figure out any sort of convention that will do the job.

So, can it be done?  Or should I accept my fate, get `.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<. . .` into my clipboard, and start banging away on some IWindsorInstallers?